# SQL Server Extended Events cannot find the path specified

Tags: sql-server

I'm following along here: [Quick Start Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

When I run my script, I get the following error:

> The target, "XXXXXXXX.package0.event_file", encountered a configuration error during initialization.  Object cannot be added to the event session.  The operating system return error 3: 'The system cannot find the path specified.' while create the file ' c:\temp\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xel'

To clarify, here is the file target configuration bit from my code.

```
add target pacakge0.event_file
(set
   filename = N'c:\temp\xxxxxxxxxxxx.xel',
   max_file_size = (2)
)
with ( ..... )
```

Comment: Do you have a folder called “c:\temp” on the SQL Server?

Comment: On the server itself?  Probably not.  Was thinking it would write to my local disk.  Not the case?

Comment: That is a Server-side event session.  There’s a .NET library if you want to capture on the client.

Comment: That coule be useful @DavidBrowne-Microsoft what is the library name or a link to that library?

Comment: The library is Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.Linq.dll.  Installed with SSMS for sure, but I don't know if there's a NuGet package.

Comment: @kstubs, [here's a QuerableXEventData PowerShell example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206863/what-is-the-right-tool-to-process-big-xel-files-sql-server-extended-events-log), using the dll that's installed with SSMS.